# Disabling PrimeNG checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, primeng, primeng-checkbox

I'm trying to disable a PrimeNG checkbox in certain cases using the `disabled` property and setting it to *true*.  However, each time the checkbox is disabled and I click it, it refreshes the page and takes me to the rootpage `/#`.

As a test I have tried to manually disable the checkbox :

```
 <p-checkbox [ngModel]="visibleInReport()" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" [disabled]="true" binary="true" (onChange)="toggleSelection($event)"></p-checkbox>
```

From my component, the `toggleSelection()` function is the following :

```
   toggleSelection(event) {
   console.log("Updating TherapyMatch Visibility");

   this.therapyService.updateReportVisability(this.revisionId, this.therapy.id, event).subscribe((res) => {
     console.log(res);
   });

  }
```

Is the `disabled` property the correct way to prevent any action from occurring when this checkbox is clicked ?

Comment: and what about using `disabled` (without brackets) ?

Comment: @yunandtidus, Thanks for the suggestion but same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the `disabled` property the correct way to prevent any action from
>   occurring when this checkbox is clicked ?

Yes it is. And you don't need to manage a `click` event.

Have a look to this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h31bec) where I just made the `disabled` property dynamic.